# Ring homomorphisms between modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I'm reading Lang's Algebra and there's a statement at the beginning of the third chapter that's confusing me:

> Let $A$ be a ring, and let $X, X'$ be $A$-modules. We denote by $\text{Hom}_A(X', X)$ the set of $A$-homomorphisms of $X'$ into $X$. Then $\text{Hom}_A(X', X)$ is an abelian group, the law of addition being that of addition for mappings into an abelian group.

In the first section of the same chapter, Lang defines $A$-homomorphisms to be **ring** homomorphisms. But $X$ and $X'$ are modules, and over the same ring! What exactly are those homomorphisms, then? How can he defines them between modules?

Comment: I don't have Lang in front of me at the moment, but usually $\text{Hom}_A(X',X)$ is defined to be the set of $A$-module homomorphisms of $X'$ into $X$.  I would say that's what he means.

Comment: Can you quote the first section of the chapter?

Comment: @MP2 I thought that too at first, but then I can't get through the second part of the statement. What operation would be "addition for mappings"? The only operation I know on homomorphisms is composition, but I can't be once I'm talking about different modules.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan "By a module-homomorphism one means a map of one module into another (over the same ring), which is an additive group-homomorphism. It is then clear that the collection of A-modules is a category, whose morphisms are the module-homomorphisms, also called homomorphisms for simplicity, if no confusion is possible. If we wish to refer to the ring A, we also say that $f$ is a A-homomorphism, or also that it is an A-linear map."

Comment: Addition makes sense in $X$ (since it is an abelian group), so you can define $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$. Also, at no point in the quote you have posted does Lang say that $A$-module homomorphisms are ring homomorphisms.

Comment: Wouldn't the law of addition be defined as follows: for $f,g\in{}\text{Hom}_A(X',X)$ and $x\in{}X'$ then $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$?

Comment: @MP2 yes, that makes sense. I've tried that before but I've made a mistake verifying  if it satisfied the group axioms. It's all correct now.

Comment: @DavidHill I understand it now, thanks. One of the confusing points for me though, was Lang writing "A-homomorphism" instead of "A-module homomorphism" or simply "module homomorphism" on the second section, once he defined "A-homomorphism" to be ring homomorphisms on the first section.

Comment: Terminology can be tricky...